# I am trying to figure out why I am getting the two error messages that I am, and how to fix them. I am using python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having trouble with the errors in the picture. It says that my dictionary 'rooms' is not even being referenced. I am not sure what to do or how to fix this. I don't have a lot of experience with dictionaries. I am still learning python and I am struggling with this code. I am about to pull my hair out honestly.

```
# Define player location and state current inventory
def player_location():
    print('-' * 20)
    print('You are in the {}'.format(location))
    print('Inventory: ', inventory)
    print('-' * 20)

def get_new_location(location, player_move):
    new_state = location
    if location in rooms:
        if player_move in rooms[location]:
            new_state = rooms[location][player_move]

    return new_state

def get_room_item(location):
    return rooms[location]['Item']

# Function to show instructions and welcome players to the game.
def show_instructions():
    print("Welcome to the Saga of Light Text Adventure Game!")
    print("Collect 6 items to win the game, or be beaten by The Dark Elf Nebo.")
    print("Movement commands: North, South, East, West, or Exit to leave the Game.")
    print("Add to Inventory: Get 'Item'")


def main_gameplay():
    # Dictionary linking rooms and items obtained in them.
    rooms = {
    'Main Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom', 'North': 'library', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'West': 
    'Music Room'},
    'Music room': {'East': 'Main Hall', 'Item': 'Music Box'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Main Hall', 'East': 'Safe room', 'Item': 'Cloak of Strength'},
    'Safe room': {'West': 'Bedroom', 'Item': 'Bow & Arrows'},
    'Dining Room': {'South': 'Kitchen', 'Item': 'The Dark Elf Nebo'},
    'Kitchen': {'West': 'Main Hall', 'North': 'Dining Room', 'Item': 'Energy Drink'},
    'Study': {'West': 'Library', 'Item': 'Ring of Light'},
    'Library': {'East': 'Study', 'South': 'Main Hall', 'Item': 'Book'}
}

rooms = main_gameplay()
# Call for the function to display instructions
show_instructions()

# variables for the current room and player moves and empty inventory list.
location = 'Great Hall'
player_move = ''
inventory = []

# gameplay loop for game
while len(inventory) < 6:
    player_location()
    player_move = input('Which direction would you like to go?\n').title()  # Ask player 
                for direction to go.
    if player_move == 'Exit':  # If Exit is selected, game over.
        location = 'Exit'
        print('Thank you for playing!')  # Thank you message for playing
    if 'Item' in rooms[get_new_location(location, player_move)]:
        print('You see a ', 'Item')
        if player_move == ('Get Item'):
            inventory = inventory.append()
    else:  # using if/else statements and dict for rooms and telling players where they 
            are.
        location = get_new_location(location, player_move)
        print(location)
        if location in rooms:
            if location == 'Main Hall':
                print()
            elif location == 'Safe Room':
                print()
            elif location == 'Bedroom':
                print()
        else:
            print("Move not valid. Please try again.")  # Error message for invalid 
                                                          direction.
        if len(inventory)==6:
            print('Congratulations! You have collected all items and defeated the 
                  dragon!') 
    exit(0)
    main_gameplay()
```

Errors that I am receiving:

```
line 61, in <module>
if 'Item' in rooms[get_new_location(location, player_move)]:
NameError: name 'rooms' is not defined
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Thank you, I think I corrected it. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rooms = main_gameplay()` assigns whatever the function `main_gameplay` returns to the variable `rooms`. While you create a variable `rooms` within the function `main_gameplay`, the function `main_gameplay` does not return anything, in other words, it implicitly returns `None` (`rooms` is only in the local scope of the function `main_gameplay`). Thus, at the global scope, the variable `rooms` is `None`. This is why you get the error message `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.` Simply add `return rooms` at the end of your declaration of the function `main_gameplay`.

Comment: I am now getting a new error code though. I updated the post to reflect it. Thank you again!

Comment: @F8thBuiltCoder - please do not continually morph your question as you find answers. If someone answers your question, you should accept it. If you are having other problems, attempt to solve it yourself then ask a new question.